# Require a user to select at least one HTML checkbox

Tags: html, database, forms

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="Restorative"><label for="">Restorative</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="Esthetics"><label for="">Esthetics</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="Implants"><label for="">Implants</label>
```

The checkboxes are all related to Sending value to the database. The user must select at least one

Restorative
        
        Esthetics
        
        Implants

How can I achieve this without using the select option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cancel the submit event with `event.preventDefault()`. Then iterate through the checkboxes and if there is at least one of them that's checked: `checkboxObj.checked` then submit the form: `formObj.submit()`. But if there's nothing checked -- reveal an error notification.

---

### Demo

**Details commented in demo**

```js
// Reference the form
var form = document.forms[0];

// Register the form to the submit event
form.onsubmit = validate;

/*
Called on submit event...
Prevent the form from submitting
Reference all form controls in form
Collect all [name=category] into an array
Iterate through the [name=category]
If one of them is checked submit the form
Otherwise reveal the error notification
*/
function validate(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var ui = this.elements;
  var chx = Array.from(ui.category);
  for (let c of chx) {
    if (c.checked) {
      this.submit();
    }
  }
  ui.req.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
:root {
  font: 400 16px/1 Consolas
}

input,
label {
  display: inline-block;
  font: inherit;
  height: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  vertical-align: middle
}

[type=submit] {
  float: right
}

#req {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #fed;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  bottom: 100px;
  left: 175px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<form id='form'>
  <fieldset>
    <input id='res' name="category" type="checkbox" value="Restorative">
    <label for="res">Restorative</label>
    <br>
    <input id='est' name="category" type="checkbox" value="Esthetics">
    <label for="est">Esthetics</label>
    <br>
    <input id='imp' name="category" type="checkbox" value="Implants">
    <label for="imp">Implants</label>
    <br>
    <input type='submit'>
  </fieldset>
  <output id='req'>Please check at least checkbox</output>
</form>
```

Comment: If this answer resolved your **first question**, click the checkmark ✅ of this post to accept it. As for your second question, you'll have to post a new question separate from this current question.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using JavaScript! All you need is to add an ID to the checkbox(s) you want to be required, then link it with the following JavaScript code.

`document.getElementById("myCheck").required = true;`

to be fired when the form is submitted.

You can see more about this by clicking [here.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_required.asp)

Comment: I think that will fire required on all of them. I want the option not to require all if the user selects one out of the three.

Comment: If you add an ID to just the one you want to be required, and then select that ID with the code. Then it will only require the one. :) Don't worry, as long as you don't have duplicate ID's for multiple things, you should be fine.

Comment: oh so that means I will skip the html required. I think I am getting it

Comment: Precisely, simply add the code above to the function fired, and it will check if the object with the specified ID is checked, if so; It will continue--if else; it will stop.

Comment: The downside is I think if the user does not choose one it will skip over and the form will be sent without the value from that category. What do you think?

Comment: What if you added an `if` statement then? To check if variable x is checked? and you can set x to your document checker. So you could do https://hastebin.com/ixiriguxoj.cs